# Why are multiple branches of a match expressions evaluated?

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I am using a `match` expression and getting a much different result than I expected. In my case the value of `wi.State` = `"Done"` so I expected the `wi.Close()` call to be executed and that's it. However it runs that and then runs the statements that come after the `_ ->` catch-all match as well. Clearly I misunderstand how these expressions are supposed so work so I will appreciate any pointers.

```
workItemCollection.Cast<WorkItem>()
|> Seq.iter(fun wi ->
    wi.Open()
    match wi.State with
    | "Done"
    | "Removed" -> 
        wi.Close()
    | _ ->
        printfn "Closing %s ->  %i" iccmCallNumber wi.Id
        wi.State <- "Done"
        wi.History <- wi.History + "Closed by Iccm to Tfs integration"
        wi.Save())
```

Comment: Are you positive that `wi.Close()` is being called in _the same_ invocation of the lambda as the catch-all, and that it's not just that there are multiple items in the sequence? Because your expectations are certainly correct otherwise...

Comment: Do you have any asynchronous operations in `wi.Open()` ? Do you perform other operations on `workItemCollection` in the another thread?

Comment: @ildjarn Apparently not. I was seeing it stop on this line in the debugger and then it proceeded to run the lines in the catch-all branch. Even though the debugger made a stop on wi.Close() and highlighted that line it did not execute it. I added a printfn to verify. False alarm.

Comment: @RomanDibikhin As far as I know the work items API I am using here is synchronous.

Comment: Debugging issues with F# are not uncommon in the least. :-]